# "brew install osm2pgsql" failed

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew, openstreetmap

I'm using mac and I want to install `osm2pgsql` to import `OSM` data into `PostgreSQL`.

I execute `brew install osm2pgsql` in the terminal. (I have already executed `brew update`).

Here is the output:

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/archive/v0.82.0.zip
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/osm2pgsql-0.82.0.zip
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --with-proj=/usr/local/opt/proj
checking for fork... yes
checking for xml2-config... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking for xml2 libraries... yes
checking for zlib compression library... no
configure: error: required library not found

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

And here is the output of executing `brew doctor`:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFFileMonitor.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.I.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFsqlite3.7.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFSyncEngine.I.dylib
```

I don't know these dylibs and should I delete them?

What should I do to linstall `osm2pgsql`?

Or should I give up `osm2pgsql` and use some other tool to import `OSM` data into `PostgreSQL`?

**[EDIT 1]**

According to http://www.zlib.net/, zlib is already included as part of Mac OS X.

And when I search it in google, I found this https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/issues/205 and this https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/issues/538

So I execute the following two commands:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install zlib
```

And the result output is:

```
==> Downloading http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8
==> make install
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only: so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include

==> Summary
```

It seems that I don't have to install zlib.

Again I execute `brew install osm2pgsql`, but it still doesn't work.

**[Edit 2]**

I give up homebrew and install osm2pgsql via a binary installer.

FYI:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Binary_Installer
https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/15

Comment: for the `brew doctor` problem, see http://dissociatedpress.net/blog/2012/11/18/til-how-to-find-the-program-that-owns-files-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about `brew` but according to the error message you are missing the `zlib` library. Try to install it first.

And you should keep to `osm2pgsql` because it is the standard tool to import OSM data into a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the formula by using the following command:

```
brew edit <formula_name>
```

Then, you have to make the exports needed in the brew env, the best place to do this is in the install function just before the call of

```
system "./configure", *args
```

Here are the lines to append

```
ENV.append 'LDFLAGS', "-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
ENV.append 'CPPFLAGS', "-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
```

When it is finished, you just have to run the brew installation again and it will works

Answer (score 0):

I edited the formula, as it was not running on Mac OS X Mavericks either. See the gist which made it install successfully.

https://gist.github.com/christoph-buente/e18584e312bcadfe82e5

And i filed a pull request to the homebrew repository. Hopefully it will be merged:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/29862